# Javascript how to sum tables

Tags: javascript

Hello I have a problem with such a task I totally don't know how to get down to it, I hope someone will help me to write an application allowing to calculate the sum and the difference of two 2-dimensional numerical tables. Each of these tables should have 2 lines and 3 columns. Input data - the values of individual array elements - enter the keypads. Present the results on screen, on the same website.
My code is below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">

<head>
  <title> JavaScript: tablice 2-wymiarowe. </title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form1">
    Podaj 12 liczb <br />
    Pierwsza: <input id="input1" type="text" value="1" /><br />
    Druga: <input id="input2" type="text" value="2" /><br />
    Trzecia: <input id="input3" type="text" value="3" /><br />
    Czwarta: <input id="input4" type="text" value="4" /><br />
    piata: <input id="input5" type="text" value="5" /><br />
    szosta: <input id="input6" type="text" value="6" /><br />
  </form>
  <button onclick="przetwarzanie();"> Oblicz </button>
  <div id="div1"> </div>
  <script>
    function przetwarzanie() {
      var input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
      var input2 = document.getElementById("input2");
      var input3 = document.getElementById("input3");
      var input4 = document.getElementById("input4");
      var input5 = document.getElementById("input5");
      var input6 = document.getElementById("input6");
      var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
      var tablica = [];
      tablica[0] = Number(input1.value, input2.value, input3.value);
      tablica[1] = Number(input4.value, input5.value, input6.value);
      suma = tablica[0] + tablica[1];
    }
    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = "Suma = " + suma;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the last line of your script is outside the function while it uses a variable that is inside, this will not work but can easily be fixed by moving the line inside the function.

The second issue is that `Number` converts a string to a number. It does not sum them up. Instead move each input value to it's own `Number` function and add them together with the `+` sign.

For the difference in the two numbers you can just subtract one from the other. With [Math.abs()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) we turn the number into a positive. This way we don't need to think about which of the two numbers is higher.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">

<head>
  <title> JavaScript: tablice 2-wymiarowe. </title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form1">
    Podaj 12 liczb <br />
    Pierwsza: <input id="input1" type="text" value="1" /><br />
    Druga: <input id="input2" type="text" value="2" /><br />
    Trzecia: <input id="input3" type="text" value="3" /><br />
    Czwarta: <input id="input4" type="text" value="4" /><br />
    piata: <input id="input5" type="text" value="5" /><br />
    szosta: <input id="input6" type="text" value="6" /><br />
  </form>
  <button onclick="przetwarzanie();"> Oblicz </button>
  <div id="div1"> </div>
  <div id="div2"> </div>
  <script>
    function przetwarzanie() {
      var input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
      var input2 = document.getElementById("input2");
      var input3 = document.getElementById("input3");
      var input4 = document.getElementById("input4");
      var input5 = document.getElementById("input5");
      var input6 = document.getElementById("input6");
      var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
      var tablica = [];
      tablica[0] = Number(input1.value) + Number(input2.value) + Number(input3.value);
      tablica[1] = Number(input4.value) + Number(input5.value) + Number(input6.value);
      
      var suma = tablica[0] + tablica[1];
      var roznica = Math.abs(tablica[0] - tablica[1]);
      
      document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = "Suma = " + suma;
      document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "Różnica = " + roznica;
    }
    
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suma undefined means you never created a variable and then you used it which caused the error below code is working just put all your code inside onclick function so when clicked it calculates and add it to html.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">

<head>
  <title> JavaScript: tablice 2-wymiarowe. </title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form1">
    Podaj 12 liczb <br />
    Pierwsza: <input id="input1" type="text" value="1" /><br />
    Druga: <input id="input2" type="text" value="2" /><br />
    Trzecia: <input id="input3" type="text" value="3" /><br />
    Czwarta: <input id="input4" type="text" value="4" /><br />
    piata: <input id="input5" type="text" value="5" /><br />
    szosta: <input id="input6" type="text" value="6" /><br />
  </form>
  <button onclick="przetwarzanie();"> Oblicz </button>
  <div id="div1"> </div>
  <script>
    function przetwarzanie() {
      var input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
      var input2 = document.getElementById("input2");
      var input3 = document.getElementById("input3");
      var input4 = document.getElementById("input4");
      var input5 = document.getElementById("input5");
      var input6 = document.getElementById("input6");
      var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
      var tablica = [];
      tablica[0] = Number(input1.value, input2.value, input3.value);
      tablica[1] = Number(input4.value, input5.value, input6.value);
     let suma = tablica[0] + tablica[1];
      document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = "Suma = " + suma;
    }
   
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```